# Why does shuffle generate the same permutation from the second iteration onward in the following code?

Tags: python, list, random

I am using shuffle to permute the contents of the lists. The first iteration works as expected and produces a permutation of the original list. However second iteration onward, I get the same permutation being written to the file. Why does the code not produce another permutation in the proceeding iterations?

```
import random;

f = open('GenerationNumbers.txt', 'w')

request = [ 128,
            512,
            2048,
            512,
            64,
            64,
            512,
            1024,
            1024,
            64,
           ]

#server
server = [ 4096,
           2048,
           2048
         ]

newrequest = []
newserver = []

for i in range(0, 30):
    random.shuffle(request)
    newrequest.append(request)
    random.shuffle(server)
    newserver.append(server)
    

f.write(str(newrequest)+"\n")
f.write(str(newserver))
f.flush()
f.close()
```

The following is a part of the output file:

> [[1024, 64, 512, 512, 128, 64, 2048, 64, 512, 1024], [1024, 64, 512, 512, 128, 64, 2048, 64, 512, 1024], [1024, 64, 512, 512, 128, 64, 2048, 64, 512, 1024], [1024, 64, 512, 512, 128, 64, 2048, 64, 512, 1024], [1024, 64, 512, 512, 128, 64, 2048, 64, 512, 1024] ....
>
> [[2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], [2048, 4096, 2048], ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding references to the same lists over and over again, and shuffling them in place. If you want to keep different copies of the list with different orders, you will have to copy the lists each iteration.

You could do it like this:

```
for i in range(0, 30):
    random.shuffle(request)
    newrequest.append(request[:])
    random.shuffle(server)
    newserver.append(server[:])
```